# How to find the unit tangent vector of a curve in R^3

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have this curve defined by :
\begin{align}
x & =\int_0^t \frac{(1+\cosh^3 u)\cos u \,du}{\cosh^2 u}; \\[10pt]
y & =\int_0^t \frac{(1+\cosh^3 u)\sin u \,du}{\cosh^2 u}; \\[10pt]
z & =\int_0^t \frac{(1+\cosh^3 u)\sinh u \, du}{cosh^2 u}
\end{align}
I should find $\vec{T}$,the unit tangent vector to(C) in M,so I have to use t as a parameter,is there any easy way to integrate x,y,z?

Comment: You've already parametrized it. The question is how to evaluate the integrals.

Comment: Why do we care about evaluating the integrals? If you're going to do any sort of calculus, you'll need the velocity vector of the parametrized curve, not the position vector.

Comment: I should find $\vec{T}$,the unit tangent vector to (C),using t as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
x & =\int_0^t \frac{(1+\cosh^3 u)\cos u \,du}{\cosh^2 u}; \\[10pt]
y & =\int_0^t \frac{(1+\cosh^3 u)\sin u \,du}{\cosh^2 u}; \\[10pt]
z & =\int_0^t \frac{(1+\cosh^3 u)\sinh u \, du}{cosh^2 u}
\end{align}$$ implies that $$ \frac {dx}{dt}=\frac{(1+\cosh^3 t)\cos t }{\cosh^2 t }$$$$ \frac {dy}{dt}=\frac{(1+\cosh^3 t)\sin t }{\cosh^2 t }$$$$ \frac {dy}{dt}=\frac{(1+\cosh^3 t)\sinh t }{\cosh^2 t }$$ We scale the results to get a tangent vector $$ V = (cost,sint,sinht)$$ Upon normalizing, we get a unit tangent vector $$T=\frac {1}{cosht} (cost,sint,sinht)$$

Comment: How can you change the variable u into t?I don't understand this process

Comment: This is Fundamental Theorem of Calculs. Derivatives of anti derivative is the original function and you evaluate at the t so it turns into a function of t